# Windows Forms control that behaves like the ASP.NET Ajax AutoComplete extender?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Successfully using the [AJAX Control Toolkit AutoComplete extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx), I'm looking for a Windows Forms 2.0 control that behaves similar to it:

[image: AutoComplete extender]

Since I want to use the control to enter multiple e-mail receivers, my primary requirement is to have *multiple*, independent items to auto-complete.

I.e. this *cannot* be done by the standard auto complete feature of a [`TextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) which only supports auto-completing one string.

In other words, I'm looking for something similar than Outlook's e-mail text box (but not as advanced, just the auto-complete part, no underlining required):

[image: Autocomplete in Outlook]

Even after searching Google (and Bing) for quite a long time I manage to have no luck in finding such a control.

**My question:**

Is there some example out there on how to build such a control, or even a finished control to use?

Since the application should be very slim, I do not want to use 3rd party libraries like DevExpress or Telerik or Infragistics.

**Update 2014-12-24:**

The commercial DevExpress library now has a [Token Edit Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17088) that might just be the control I was looking for:

[image]

Comment: my boss was looking for this and ended up writing his own. This may be the way to go!

Comment: @DanielCasserly Can your boss share his source code for it?

Comment: unlikely sorry. However, it can be done!! :-)

Comment: Not to sound whining, I never understood why anyone would _not_ share its source code. I've gained so much knowledge and help over the years from the community and in turn [provided dozens of articles](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=235). Never had any bad experience with that.

Comment: Sorry if i'd written it i would do.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the IAutoComplete interface. That will let you create a class that you can use instead of the standard auto-complete for an edit box. In that class you would handle what part of the string you are auto-completing on and the source of where the data is coming from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292(v=VS.85).aspx